# Create function to find the maximum digit in integer X

Tags: c, function

I'm a student, and my task is "An integer X is given, find the maximum of the numbers included in its composition." For example X is 786534, so maximum number is "8". The task have to be done with function on c. I make some notes but it doesn't work correctly. There are two functions.
First function is for input number a check it for right size.
The second is for the calculating the max digit.
I have a problem with calling the function.
What is my mistake?

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_N 999999999999

int inputNumber() 
{
    int number;
    printf("Input number:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &number);
    while (number = 0 && number > MAX_N)
    {
        // Number is not equal 0
        printf("Repeat input:\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &number);
    }
    return number;
}

int findMax(int number)
{
    int max_number; //intermediate variable
    int a = number;
    max_number = a % 10;
    a = a / 10;
    while (a > 0) 
    {
        if (a % 10 > max_number)
            max_number = a % 10;
        a = a / 10;
    }
    return max_number;
}

int main() 
{
    inputNumber();
    findMax();
    printf("The maimum number is %d\n", max_number);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Typo here: `while (number = 0 ....` Use `==` for comparison.

Comment: Your definition `#define MAX_N 999999999999` is also unsafe. In a system with 32-bit integers, this is liable to overflow, resulting in a value of -727379969, which is going to cause problems.

Comment: @r3mainer It's not necessarily going to overflow - it will just be treated as a 64-bit integer value on systems that have them, causing the check for a maximum value to fail every time. On systems without 64-bit integers, though, [the C standard states](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1p6):  "If an integer constant cannot be represented by any type in its list and has no extended integer type, then the integer constant has no type."  What happens then is probably a question for the language lawyers. Hopefully the compiler will fail to compile the code.

Comment: Were you specifically told to assume an `int` value? Otherwise, read the input as a string, check that it's made of only digits, then return the largest one. This requires no arithmetic conversion, and is not bound by the size limits of the C integer types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, let's look at this:

```
int main() 
{
    inputNumber();
    findMax();
    printf("The maimum number is %d\n", max_number);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

inputNumber returns an int, but you don't store it somewhere. So this might work better for you:

```
    int number = inputNumber();
```

findMax expects an argument, so this might work better:

```
    int max_number = findMax(number);
```

That should get you further.

Comment: yeah this correct but sir you missed this part (  while (number = 0 && number > MAX_N)) in the inputNumber function ..this should be  while (number ==0 && number > MAX_N)

Comment: I was answering his question. He was having a problem calling his functions :-)

Comment: okay..yeah ..i think he'll figure the rest out.. : )

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the return value of inputNumber() to a variable and pass that as the parameter to findMax(); variables such as "max_number" are limited by function scope.

I hope this helps!